# How can I pass mysql data as ajax parameter

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, prototypejs

I want to create a program where I can delete mysql records using button with ajax. My problem is that I don't know how to pass a mysql data as ajax parameter so if it matches with the query in the php file, it will be removed. I created one with php alone but it's a static program, I want it to be dynamic with ajax.

**index.php :**

```
    <?php

    require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM statuspost ORDER BY id DESC");

    while($i = $query->fetch_object()){

 echo $i->post ?><button onclick='ajaxWallpost('.<?php 
    $i->id ?>.')'>Remove</button>

<?php
    }
    ?>

            <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype  
    /1.7.2.0/prototype.js'></script>
                <script>

                    function ajaxWallpost(status){

                        new Ajax.Request('wallpost.php?type=post&  
    id='+status, {
                      method:'get',
                      onSuccess: function(transport) {

                      },
                      onFailure: function() { alert('Something went   
    wrong...'); }
                    });

                    }

                </script>
```

**wallpost.php :**

```
<?php

require_once 'dbconfig.php';

if(isset($_GET['id'], $_GET['type'])){

    $post = $_GET['type'];
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

    switch($post){

        case 'post':
            $con->query("DELETE FROM statuspost WHERE id={$id}");
        break;

    }

}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this it will work :**

Since AJAX happens "behind the scenes" (so to speak) your redirect will just interrupt the response to your javascript handler. So PHP cannot redirect your browser now, `javascript` can. So use `javascript` to redirect the user.

You'll need to return the URL and have your callback kick the browser to a new location.

"*You're doing the ajax call - the php header will redirect the ajax response... not the page that the user is currently sitting on. You will have to modify your javascript code in the client to change the location.*"

A javascript redirect is as simple as window.location.href = "http://mylocation";

**Solution to your problem with Ajax and Javascript :**

```
<script>

       function ajaxWallpost(status){

          new Ajax.Request('wallpost.php?type=post&id='+status, {
                      method:'get',
                      onSuccess: function(transport)
                      {
                       window.location.href = "index.php";
                      },
                      onFailure: function() 
                      { 
                       alert('Something went wrong...'); 
                      }
                          });
                                  }
</script>
```

**Solution to your problem without Ajax and Javascript :**

```
 <?php

    require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    if(isset($_GET['id'], $_GET['type'])){

    $post = $_GET['type'];
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

    switch($post){

        case 'post':
            $con->query("DELETE FROM statuspost WHERE id={$id}");
        break;

    }

}

    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM statuspost ORDER BY id DESC");

    while($i = $query->fetch_object())
{
?>

    <a href="index.php?id=<?php $i->id ?>&type=post>Remove</a>

<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi, I wanna say thank you for editing my thread, however, my only problem is that I can't seem to find a way to delete records via ajax. I need to pass the id of the post from the database as parameter but I don't know how. I tried a few things but it won't do anything. What I mean by the redirect page is that I'm only sharing that I made a static one using just php where if I click the remove text which is an <a> tag, then it redirects me to another page for the delete query to run, then it redirects me again using the header.

Comment: @Renboy, I updated my answer according to your question.2nd solution is best for you. try it it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP redirect just says "The thing you were looking for? It's actually over there."

It won't make the browser stop processing it using XHR and start processing it as if you followed a link.

The contents of `index.php` will be in `transport.responseText`.

If you want to send the browser to a new page, then don't use Ajax.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my thread, my real problem is that I want to delete records via ajax but I need to pass a data from database as ajax parameter so if it matches with the query, then that specific post will be deleted.